# I need to rotate this parabola around the y axis, but can't find the correct expression

Tags: integration, conic-sections, solid-of-revolution

I need to revolve this parabola $360$ degrees about the $y$ axis (to find volume of revolution).

$y = -0.399x^2 + 0.0232x + 5.68$

But I cannot express it in the form $x^2 = f(y)$, which is required for the integration calculation.

Can someone help me find the correct expression? I have no idea about how to leave $x^2$ alone and write it in terms of $y$...

Comment: Have you learned about volumes of integration by cylindrical shells?

Comment: I don't recommend this but.... you could put everything on one side of the equal sign. i.e. $ax^2 + bx + c - y = 0$ and apply the quadratic formula... $x = \frac {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac + 4ay}}{2a}$

Comment: Yes we learned the cylindrical shells method. Would any other method be easier to apply here?  @DougM

Comment: I tried to write the parabola in vertex form and found an aswer, but the problem is that it has a squareroot in it, which is not defined in the interval I want to integrate in. So, I am concerned about using the quadratic formula too...

Comment: Use shells! $V = 2\pi \int (ax^2 + bx + c)(x) dx$  (and you haven't included your limits of integration.)

Comment: @DougM but isn't shell method used for finding the volume of hollow objects? Would it be correct to use it in my case?

Comment: Nope.  Shells works great here.  As a rule, use shells when revolving around they y axis and use disks when revolving around the x-axis.

Comment: @DougM I figured it out! Thanks a bunch, you saved my life :)